# Export / Import Xamarin.Essentials Preferences

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I was looking for a quick / simple way to import and export the Preferences object exposed by Xamarin.Essentials.  Any suggestions?

Comment: it doesn't look like it's easily serializable.  You can check the source yourself: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/tree/master/Xamarin.Essentials/Preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was not able to find a built in way to do this.  I had to manually write code in my app to go through all my preferences, serialize them and them write the string to disk.  Likewise for import I had to take a serialized string, reserialize it and then manually place the values back in my preferences.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you want to save data in preference and get data from Preferences, am I right? if yes, please take a look the following code:

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;
  private void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Preferences.Set("key1", "this is test");
    }

    private void Btn2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myValue = Preferences.Get("key1","");
    }
```

More detailed info about Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences, please take a look the following article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-application-preferences-using-xamarin-essentials/

**Update:**

If you want to save everything in Preferences, I suggest you can  Serialization the data you want to save and deserialization the data that you want to get using Newtonsoft.Json.

Firstly, install Newtonsoft.Json by Nuget package, then do this:

```
public partial class Page13 : ContentPage
{
   public List<person> persons { get; set; }
    public Page13()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        persons = new List<person>()
        {
            new person(){username="cherry",age=12},
            new person(){username="barry",age=14}
        };

    }

    private void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons);
        Preferences.Set("key1", list);
    }

    private void Btn2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myValue = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<person>>(Preferences.Get("key1", "")) ;
    }    
}


public class person
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

I use List to do example, but you can Serialization evertthing object to string, then save this string in Preference, deserialization string in to object to get data.

Comment: that is not correct.  I want to export everything I have saved into the preferences so it can be saved to a drive then re-imported to the preferences in the future.  This would be used in a case where a user wants to stand up another instance of my app with the exact same configuration.

Comment: @George, You said that you want to save everything in preferences, if this, I suggest you can Serialization the data you want to save and deserialization the data that you want to get using **Newtonsoft.Json**,please take a look my update. If my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: Yes that is the last resort.  I was looking for something a little more dynamic so that when I add a new value to my preferences, it is automatically included in import/export.  I am going to work on an idea I had today and will post back here if it works.

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr, If you have one solution about this, please share you way here, thanks.

Comment: @ CherryBu - I was hoping the Xamarin Essentials preferences exposed a keys collection.  With that it would be very easy to loop through all the entries in the preferences, serialize them to json and make that string available to be saved.  Unfortunately, the preferences class does not expose a keys collection.  I had to manually implement it in my code instead.  I believe exposing a collection of keys would be a great addition to the preferences class and make the import export function trivial to implement. :)